Can I restore a list panel to Krusader?
I'm using Krusader file manager 2.7.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.  I opened a Krusader window with its normal two panels, then I shrank it horizontally to see it while working with a different program.  Nicely, it eliminated the inactive panel automatically so that I could see the active panel better.  Props to whichever dev thought of making it do that.
After re-expanding the window, I still only have the one panel.  Is it possible to restore a 2nd panel to Krusader?  I've searched through the menu and settings and done web searches for info online, but I can't find anything.  The docs don't mention this particular case.
Once eliminated, can I restore a second list panel to Krusader?
